# How to transmit a function to anonymous pipe WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe

I need to write to anonymous pipe something like `double (*fun)(double)`, but the following `WriteFile(pipe, fun, 4, written_bytes, 0)` causes an error in a pipe-receiver while `ReadFile(read_pipe, fun, 4, written_bytes, 0)`. Are there any methods to do this?

I have an idea. I can create a struct with field of same type:

```
struct Foo
{
    double (*f)(double);
};
```

And then I write it `WriteFile(hWritePipe_StdIN, &to_process, sizeof(Foo), &bytes, 0);`
But I have problem, that pipe-receiver never ends to read data:
`ReadFile(hReadPipe, &to_process, sizeof(Foo), &bytes, 0);`

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you want to send the function itself? Or do you want to call the function and transmit the result?

Comment: @StackedCrooked First version. I want to send the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with it:

First, you should know the size of function.
If you do, you just call `WriteFile(pipe, funcPtr, funcSize, ...)` to transfer it.

Second, the function should contain only [position-independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), and don't address any data. 
E.g. a function like this won't work:

```
double fun(double x)
{
    int arr[10000]; // implicit function call (alloca or something like this)
    printf("some");
    static int some = 1;
    return globalVal + (++some);
}
```

because function `printf` will have a different address and there will be no static variable and string in another process.
(Well, maybe you can transfer data as well, but there is no way you'll generate PI code.)

So, with all that limitations, you can send a function:

```
__declspec(naked) double fun(double x) { __asm ret }

const auto funcSize = 1;
WriteFile(pipe, &fun, funcSize, ...);
```

Comment: how I can use this function after receiving? I need something like `fun = cos` to work with.

Answer (score 2):

In native code you can not send function (the code) itself, neither to the same nor to different process. (You could try low-level hacking like the one @Abyx suggests, but it seriously limits functionality that the code can perform, and will probably make you resort to writing it all in assembler by hand.)

You also can't send function's address to another process, because each process has its own isolated address space; in another process, that address will contain different data.

The solution will be to create a shared library (preferably dynamic) that will contain all functions that could possibly be sent this way. Assign each function some tag (e.g. number or name), let DLL maintain a mapping between tags and addresses. Then send tags instead.

Comment: +1 Using a DLL and sending the symbol name (cave mangling!) is an ingenious idea.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve, here? Are you really trying to write the *function* itself? Why? That's not something you can easily do in C++, for instance because the size of a function is not well-defined.

You should probably write the *data*, i.e. the number returned by `fun()` instead:

```
const double value = fun(input);
DWORD numberOfBytesWritten;
WriteFile(pipe, &value, sizeof value, &numberOfBytesWritten, NULL);
```

You should of course add code to check the output. Note that writing binary data like this can be brittle.

Comment: I really need to write _function_ itself, because this function will be used in a child process like `fun(input)`. I haven't any input in a parent process to write the data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using WinAPI, the native way to send a function is via COM. In particular, expose the function as a method on a COM object, obtain a COM moniker, and send the moniker. Monikers can be serialized and sent over pipes. The other side can deserialize the moniker and get access to your object.

Under water, this works by looking up the object in the COM *Running Object Table*

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how this is excessively complicated and error-prone to do in C++ (and only works with a very limited set of functions at all), I recommend you use a scripting language for this. Instruction caches and DEP are another two things you'd have to consider in addition to the already mentioned ones.

Really. Transmit the function as script, and run it on the other end. Save yourself that pain.

Angelscript looks and feels almost like C++, so that might be a possible candidate.

Now, if you object to this because you need something that a script cannot trivially do, knoweth: C++ will not be able to do it either, in this scenario.

Apart from the above mentioned PIC code issue (@Abyx) and the fact that you cannot safely or portably know a function's size, the only C++ functions that you could conceivably send via a pipe and execute in a meaningful manner are strictly const functions. Here, const is in the sense of e.g. GCC's `__attribute__((const))`, not the C++ `const` keyword.

That is, any such function *may not examine any values except its arguments, and have no effects except the return value*. The reason is obvious: A different process lives in a different address space, so anything you reference is meaningless. Anything you change is meaningless.
Now, this is just what a script can do, in a safe, straightforward manner, and reliably. The overhead is, considering you already send code through a pipe, neglegible.